# Wordpress accordion plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to make a wordpress site with a rather specific plugin.
Like in this picture.

[Picture 1](http://leopold.nu/bilder/1.jpg)
(it doesn't have to be click activated)

I'd like to have a ready plugin for this but I can change it if it doesn't do exactly the right thing.
The closest I have come to finding this is a Jquery horizontal accordion. But it limited to having a small title rather than having 3 "half opened" textboxes with a small description [like this.](http://outdatedbrowser.com/en)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found it at [devsmash.com/projects/kwicks/2.2.x/examples/horizontal](http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks/2.2.x/examples/horizontal)